# PostgreSQL now() function gives different results EFCore and DBeaver

Tags: .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core

First I try to execute from an app using EF Core 7 on my local system.

```
public class SqlResponse
{
    public DateTime Now { get; set; }
}
```

```
var sql = @"select now()::timestamp";
using IDbConnection con = _context.Database.GetDbConnection();
var result = (await con.QueryAsync<SqlResponse>(sql)).ToList();
```

`result[0].Now` returns `3.08.2023 11:00:23`

Then I execute the query below on DBeaver. The DB is on remote machine.

```
SELECT now()::timestamp;
```

The query returns `2023-08-03 14:00:32.628` value.

My DB's timezone is Europe/Istanbul
`SHOW TIMEZONE;`

| TimeZone |
| --- |
| Europe/Istanbul |

And I check on my Windows 10 cmd line:

```bash
C:\Users\tolgacakir>tzutil /g
Turkey Standard Time
```

The NuGet packages that I used:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="7.0.3" />
```

Comment: The two connections have a different setting of `timezone`.

Comment: The two different questions suffer from the same thing. If you want to equalize them use `timestamp with time zone  at time zone`. For example; `select now()::timestamp with time zone  at time zone 'America/Denver';`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the SqlResponse class to use DateTimeOffset:

```
public class SqlResponse
{
    public DateTimeOffset Now { get; set; }
}
```

Update the query to use timestamp with time zone:

```
var sql = @"select now()::timestamp with time zone";
```

Adjust the EF Core application's timezone to Europe/Istanbul. This can be done in the ConfigureServices method in your Startup.cs file:

```
// Add the following using statements at the top of your file
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

// Inside your Startup.cs or wherever you configure your services
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // other configurations

services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("YourConnectionString"))
           .UseTimeZone("Europe/Istanbul"); // Set the timezone here
});

// other configurations
}
```

With these changes, you should get consistent results between EF Core and DBeaver, both displaying timestamps in the Europe/Istanbul timezone.

Comment: I couldn't find UseTimeZone method in DbContextOptionsBuilder. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder?view=efcore-7.0